# Updated from 24.5.1 to 25.1, not respecting default app scaling

Tags: spacemacs, microsoft-windows

I use surface book with 3000x2000 native resolution scaled 200%. I just reinstalled (spac)emacs with 25.1 version and a new emacs frame will start the right size then immediately halve in size as it starts to load and does not respect the 200% scale.

I have tried starting emacs on 100% then scaling up and all other such combinations to no success.

A partial solution exists:

```
  (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Fira Code"))
  (set-face-attribute 'default t :font "Fira Code")
```

This will set the frame to a good level but has two issues:

1. It overwrites `dotspacemacs-default-font` options like bold, width.
2. Not everything is scaled back - in particular pylint code analysis popups are extremely small.

Once it is zoomed in it uses proper hdpi after setting `Disable display scaling on high DPI settings` option on emacs.exe.